# Node js Electron-Prompt

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Hello I am a new coder and I saw this Electron helper to prompt for a value via input. https://github.com/p-sam/electron-prompt. I was wondering how I would store the value from user input. This is the code I have but I don't really understand how to pull out the data(user input) from the code to use. I would appreciate any help, thank you!

```
async function getStoreId()
{
prompt({
      title: 'Get StoreId',
      label: 'Store ID: ',
      value: '',
      inputAttrs: {
          type: 'guid'
      },
      type: 'input'
  })
  .then((r) => {
    if(r === null) {
        console.log('user cancelled');
    } else {
        console.log('result', r);
        //storeid = r;
    }

})
.catch(console.error);
}
let storeid = await getStoreId;
console.log(storeid);
```

Comment: `const result = await prompt(...)`

Comment: @MicaelLevi when I add that, the prompt window does not come up.

Comment: you might missed to call your function (that calls `prompt`), or have missed an `await`

Answer (score 0):

The `prompt()` function in the `electron-prompt` library returns a promise.

A promise can only be in one of three states:

1. Pending
2. Fulfilled, or
3. Rejected

Quite often, due to the sequential nature of Javascript, if you try and `console.log()` a promise before it has been fulfilled, you will receive a `Promise { <pending> }` message.

As you have wrapped your own function `getStoreId()` around the `prompt()` function (which returns a promise), you will not return anything unless you place a `return` statement in front of the `prompt()` function.

As a result, your `getStoreId()` function will now return the promise.

To handle the returned promise you must follow it up with a `.then()` method. The `.then()` method will then be processed when the promise is resolved (IE: It is no longer in the 'pending' state), meaning it has either been fulfilled or 'rejected'.

Inside the `.then()` method you can extract the result and either process it then and there or pass it on to another functions of yours for clearer, cleaner, more easily readable code.

```js
function getStoreId() { // Removed async keyword
    return prompt({     // Added return statement
        title: 'Get StoreId',
        label: 'Store ID:',
        value: '',
        inputAttrs: {type: 'guid'},
        type: 'input'
    })
        .then((result) => {
            if (result === null) {
                console.log('user cancelled');
            } else {
                return result; // Return the result
            }
        })
        // PS: Don't forget to handle any caught errors gracefully.
        .catch(console.error);
}

// Called only when your getStoreId() function has resolved.
function useResult(result) {
    // Do something useful with your result.
    console.log(result);
}

// Calling "getStoreId()" without a ".then()" method will only
// return a "Promise { <pending> }" message at this point in the code.
// console.log(getStoreId());

// Let's show the prompt window.
getStoreId()
    .then((result) => { useResult(result); })
```